# Conversion of Hex string to decimal

Tags: c#, python-3.x

Guys i need some help converting this c program to python since i am not a c guy whatsoever. I'm attempting to convert this hex string. I was told the following hex string was a series of position and load integer values. The developers exact words were:

```
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
```

"The hex string is a series of 2 byte integers in pairs of Position and Load. The first 2 bytes is Position1, the next 2=Load1, next 2=Position2, next 2=Load2, etc...
A byte is 2 Hex characters. "

Here is the c# that was provided to me by the developer with little context behind it

```
public class PositionLoadPoint
{
   public float Position { get; private set; }
   public float Load { get; private set; }
    public PositionLoadPoint(float position, float load)
   {
       Position = position;
       Load = load;
   }
}
This method should return a list of points from an array of bytes:
public static IList<PositionLoadPoint> GetPositionLoadPoints(byte[] bytes)
{
   IList<PositionLoadPoint> result = new List<PositionLoadPoint>();
   int midIndex = bytes.Length / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < midIndex; i += 4)
   {
       byte[] load = new byte[4];
       byte[] position = new byte[4];
        Array.Copy(bytes, i, load, 0, 4);
       Array.Copy(bytes, midIndex + i, position, 0, 4);
        var point = new PositionLoadPoint(BitConverter.ToSingle(load, 0),
                                          BitConverter.ToSingle(position, 0));
        result.Add(point);
   }
    return result;
}
```

I'm struggling with this and its driving me crazy because i believe it should be crazy simple. Here is my python that i wrote, but i do not believe the results are correct since the plot is sporatic!

```
#INSERT LIBRARIES
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

hex_string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

#convert all two digit hex to decimal and place in list
hex_list = []
for i in range(0,len(hex_string),2):
    hex_list.append(int(hex_string[i:i+2],16))

#GROUP TWO CONSECUTIVE DECIMALS IN HEX_LIST TOGETHER UNTIL ALL DECIMALS ARE GROUPED INTO PAIRS WITHIN A LIST
DEC_list_pair = []
for i in range(0,len(hex_list),2):
    DEC_list_pair.append(hex_list[i:i+2])

#Create a x and y axis using the DEC_list_pair_no_duplicates list
x_axis = []
y_axis = []
for i in range(0,len(DEC_list_pair)):
    x_axis.append(DEC_list_pair[i][0])
    y_axis.append(DEC_list_pair[i][1])

#plot x_axis and y_axis
plt.plot(x_axis, y_axis)
plt.show()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? What do you expect the results to be and how do they differ from the expected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the description doesn't match the C# code.

```
int midIndex = bytes.Length / 2;
for (int i = 0; i < midIndex; i += 4)
{
    // Reading into 'load' from offset i from front of the array
    Array.Copy(bytes, i, load, 0, 4);
    // Reading into 'position' from offset i from midIndex of the array
    Array.Copy(bytes, midIndex + i, position, 0, 4);
    var point = new PositionLoadPoint(BitConverter.ToSingle(load, 0),
                                      BitConverter.ToSingle(position, 0));
```

All the loads are coming from the front of the array, all the postions are coming after "midIndex".

Comment: You are 100% correct here. I sent your feed back to the developer and he acknowledged he was wrong and did not spend anytime looking at the code. Thanks for giving me the feedback to get him to do something :)